# Как в wxString записать ентер?

Tags: c++, gui, wxwidgets

Как ентер сделать частью wxString строки?

Comment: А что значит "ентер"? перевод строки? `\n` уже не работает?

Comment: res+=s+=newn+='\n'+=adr+=b->city+=' '+=b->street+=' '+=newr+='\n'+=ab+=a+='\n'+=ord+=o+='\n';

error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'char' and 'wxString')

Comment: Брр... так 100% не сработает - как вы себе представляете `'\n'+=ord` - и куда, по-вашему, должен быть сохранен результат? Вы же не пишете `2+=5`, правда?

Comment: Сохраните свой перевод строки в переменную типа wxString и складывайте потом в удовольствие ;-) например, `wxString e="\n";`

Comment: как раз об  етом и думал, Спасибо

Comment: Кстати, а почему никто не заметил что писать += больше раза неправильно?

Comment: @Vladimir, напишите, пж-та, решение в ответ - получите плюсиков)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните свой перевод строки в переменную типа wxString и складывайте потом в удовольствие ;-) например, `wxString e="\n";`

Вообще, я не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотели добиться такой сложной конструкцией. В арсенале `wxString` есть много способов для формирования нужной строки. Кроме перегруженного оператора сложения (конкатенации), можно использовать функции с форматным выводом `Printf()`(аналог семейства `printf`/`sprintf`) или статический метод `wxString::Format()` (это когда хочется использовать функционал `Printf`, но не хочется явно создавать дополнительную переменную типа `wxString` - обычно используется для формирования строки из разнородных элементов - чисел, си-строк, символов и т.п.), или перегруженный оператор `<<`. Есть и аналоги функций для строк STL: `append` и `insert`. Просмотрите список доступных функций в документации `wx` и выбирайте, что больше подойдет по Вашей задаче.

И старайтесь писать код более простыми конструкциями, тогда будет и проще читать программу, и легче искать ошибки.

Примеры использования:
    int n = 10;
    double pi = 3.14;
    char p = '%';

```
wxString s1, s2, s3;
s1.Printf("Какой=то текст\t %d\t Pi = %5.3f\nВыполнено %d%c", n, pi, 23, p);
s2 =  wxString::Format("Какой=то текст\t %d\t Pi = %5.3f\nВыполнено %d%c", n, pi, 23, p);
s3 = "Снова текст"; 
s3 << pi;
```

PS: примеры набирал не проверяя, возможны опечатки.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Vladimir:

```
wxString e="\n";
r+=e;
```